# Annoying double-brackets in quotations

Tags: biblatex, citing, csquotes

I'm using csquotes and biblatex(biber) for my reference-management. Unfortunately, whenever I'm citing without referencing with an additional comment (like 'compare') my quotes look like

```
([abc12])
```

instead of just

```
[abc12]
```

which is quite annoying.

Can anyone help me with that. I feel like it's something very trivial, but I just can't figure it out.

Please see my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{my-example-bibliography.bib}      % obviously that's just for the MWE ;)
    @BOOK{ERT,  
        author =    {Ertel, Wolfgang},
        year =      {2012},
        title =     {Angewandte Kryptographie},
        edition =   {4},
        publisher = {Hanser},
        isbn =      {978-3-446-427-56-3},
        location =  {München},
        pagetotal = {223}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, parskip=half, 12pt, onehalfspacing, DIV=12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}   



\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
%------------------------------------------------------------

% Deutsche Eingabe
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     


\usepackage{hyperref}



\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt, firstinits=true]{biblatex} 
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \addbibresource{my-example-bibliography.bib} 






\begin{document}

    Oh hi! I'd like to reference to Ertel. He wrote \textquote[\cite{ERT}]{something like this!}   $\leftarrow$ looks bad\\

    But if I use a compare-quote e.g.: Here is some other valuable knowledge \\(compare \cite[p. 46]{ERT}) $\leftarrow$ looks good (I guess)

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I appreciate you help

Kind regards[image]

Comment: David's answer is the way to go here, but if for some reason someone needs to use `\textquote[\cite{...}]{...}` then `\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\space#1}` should remove the unwanted round brackets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use `\textcquote` instead which allows for a built in citation and does not include the parentheses.

(Also, there are some unrelated things you should fix: Use `giveninits` instead of `firstinits`; use `family-given` instead of `last-first`; don't end a paragraph with `\\`.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, parskip=half, 12pt, onehalfspacing, DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{ERT,
  author =    {Ertel, Wolfgang},
  year =      {2012},
  title =     {Angewandte Kryptographie},
  edition =   {4},
  publisher = {Hanser},
  isbn =      {978-3-446-427-56-3},
  location =  {München},
  pagetotal = {223}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt, giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\addbibresource{my-example-bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Oh hi! I'd like to reference to Ertel. He wrote \textcquote{ERT}{something
like this!} $\leftarrow$ looks good

But if I use a compare-quote e.g., \textcquote[compare][46]{ERT}{Here is some
other valuable knowledge.} $\leftarrow$ looks good

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output]